# Can Logic App refresh excel file in the Azure Storage (blob)?

Tags: excel, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have data source from external (KoboTool Box). This data source provides conversion to excel file (`From Web` connection) by put specific web link. After I got all data, I put these excel file in the Azure blob storage.

[image: Excel refresh data]

By using `Logic App`, I have got the file in the blob container but I have no idea how to refresh this excel file to retrieve external data. There are two `Excel Online` (One drive & Business). I don't know what next steps.

[image: Excel Online]

My question, is it possible to refresh this excel file to get the latest update data from external data source by using logic app ?

Comment: Are you trying to download excel file from KoboTool Box and upload it to azure blob?

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT, already download from KoboTool Box through 'From Web' as data source and upload the excel file into azure blob. After that, how to refresh data, is that possible ?

Comment: It automatically refreshes the blob present in your storage account while you are having any operations from excel that you have uploaded you can just refresh the logic app and it will be updated